# Move Symfony2 database to remote host

Tags: symfony

I am fairly new to Symfony2, so please bear with me. I have a Symfony2 application that is currently using a database at localhost. I moved a copy of the database to a remote host and edited my parameters.yml file to reflect the new database_host. I then ran php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug since this is a development version of the application. The application is still pulling the data from the localhost.

Do I need to clear other caching or run some other command to get the application to see the new database?

Here are the values in my parameters.yml file:

```
database_driver:   pdo_mysql
database_host:     *removed*
database_port:     3306
database_name:     target
database_user:     imac
database_password: *removed*
```

Here is the doctrine section of the config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        types:
            datetime: Target\Bundle\UserBundle\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType
```

Comment: Local database servers on the same machine are usually referred to as `localhost`.

Comment: Could you include a copy of your parameters.yml, make sure you block out your password first, though!

Comment: I know. I am trying to move away from that. I changed the database_host setting in parameters.yml from localhost to my remote host. But after clearing the cache, my application is still pulling data from the localhost and not my remote host.

Comment: There is a `config.yml` and a `config_dev.yml`. It is possible to change the settings of `config_dev.yml` to derive from the standard `config.yml` - so post that file too to be sure. Also, are you accessing `app_dev.php` when you test the app? I'm getting some obvious questions out of the way.

Comment: What does the doctrine section of your `app/config/config.yml` look like?

Comment: I edited the question above to include this information.

Comment: Your cleared the prod cache... are you also testing your db connection in prod env?

Comment: How did I clear the prod cache when I used --env=dev in my clear cache statement?

Comment: Just completely remove the app/cache directory.  That will absolutely verify it's not a caching issue.  I suspect you may have another copy of parameters.yml somewhere and you edited the wrong one.

Comment: Removing the cache directory did the trick. Thanks!!

Comment: I removed my answer so you can get credit for your suggestion.